# How can I show the keyboard when I start editing my email text field?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikeyboard

I want to show the keyboard when I start editing a text field.,i am having an email field in my view so that i want to show up key board when i begin editing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your problem actually? By default a keypad will be shown when UITextField is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to open the keyboard automatically with a field when a view is shown try:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // do other will appear stuff like call the super
    [nameinput becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Replace nameInput with your UITextField name. Hope that's what you were asking.